# HTML5 bar chart exported from Flash does not work  in IE6, IE7 or IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, html, adobe

I have made a graph using flash and have exported it to a HTML5 format. Its works fine in IE9,Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome and most of the major browsers. But I want a work around to make it work in IE 6 and 7. I tried changing the doctype but still it soen't display anything in my IE 6 browser.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Untitled</title>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime-->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="sample_edgePreload.js"></script>
    <style>
        .edgeLoad-EDGE-36508108 { display:none; }
    </style>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->

</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <div id="Stage" class="EDGE-36508108">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: see this chart http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/  some HTML5 tags not supported in IE 6.0 and 8.0...

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 6-8 rendering engines do not support HTML5, as they were built on the time when people where still hunting mammoths with sticks and this was before HTML5.

To add the support of HTML5 in Internet Explorer 6-8 consider using the following Google Chrome Frame installer Javascript:

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/#TOC-Detecting-Google-Chrome-Frame-and-Prompting-to-Install

Comment: why make people install something? there are several charting frameworks that are meant for html5 with fallbacks for older IE versions.

Comment: The question is about using HTML5 in Internet Explorer, not about legacy compatible Javascript chart frameworks

Comment: http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/chrome-frame-faq#TOC-What-is-Google-Chrome-Frame-

Comment: doesn't mean you can't give him advice on other ways to provide charts in IE other than forcing his users to install something they might not be willing to. In fact he might be flooded with mails in the future from his users exactly because of that installation prompt.